# JBOSS 5.1 High CPU usage while doing Load test

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, cpu-usage

We observe high CPU usage by jboss 5.1 while doing load test.

In **server.xml** located in **jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar** path, we have done the thread-configuration in the connector in the below way

```
<Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
         emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Also we have increased the JVM size to 1.5 gig in jboss's start-up files.

But still we see high CPU usage by the server (nearly 95 to 98 % of use) and this some times goes more and the server gets crashed and results in OutOfMemory exception.

Previously while we were having jboss 4, we were not facing this issue, but now after migrating to jboss 5 we get this. Can any one suggest on this please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [take a thread dump](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ThreadDump) and [check the memory pool usage](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowCanIDisplayTheMemoryPoolUsage) to see what's going on in your JBoss instance.